# Problemas al subir imagen usando php en un plugin personalizado de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Realize una integracion de una api de un crm para subir la propiedades a wordpress, pero estoy teniendo problemas al subir una imagen a wordpress, estoy usando la funcion de media_sideload_image y al hacer var dump en la variable dice que la url no es valida.

```
// Encolamos los archivos necesarios para subir la imagen
require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

$url = $gallery[0]['url'];

// Subimos la imagen a nuestro servidor, le pasamos la url y retornamos el ID
$image_thumbnail = media_sideload_image( $url );

var_dump($image_thumbnail);
die();
```

Comment: La función no parece ser el problema, el problema es la url, la imagen parece ser generada por medio de un script, por lo que la url no lleva a una imagen como tal, por eso no funciona, si pruebas con una url valida funcionara perfectamente. https://image.wasi.co/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJzdGF0aWN3Iiwia2V5IjoiaW5tdWVibGVzXC9nMTEwMTgyMzIwMjMxMTI3MDkzNzE3LmpwZyIsImVkaXRzIjp7Im5vcm1hbGlzZSI6dHJ1ZSwicm90YXRlIjowLCJyZXNpemUiOnsid2lkdGgiOjU1NSwiaGVpZ2h0Ijo0MTYsImZpdCI6ImNvbnRhaW4iLCJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kIjp7InIiOjI1NSwiZyI6MjU1LCJiIjoyNTUsImFscGhhIjoxfX19fQ==

Comment: Coloco la url en la variabla $url y me sigue diciendo que la url no es valida

Answer (score 0):

Hay url's que muestran imágenes pero que no son directamente la imagen.
Podrías validar la imagen con `wp_check_filetype()`

Algo así de acuerdo a tu lógica:

```
require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Asumiendo que es una imágen jpg
$url = wp_check_filetype($gallery[0]['url'])['ext'] == 'jpg' ? $gallery[0]['url'] : wp_die('No es una imagen');

// Subimos la imagen a nuestro servidor, le pasamos la url y retornamos el ID
$image_thumbnail = media_sideload_image( $url );
```

Comment: Esta es una de las url: https://image.wasi.co/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJzdGF0aWN3Iiwia2V5IjoiaW5tdWVibGVzXC9nMTEwMTgyMzIwMjMxMTI3MDkzNzE3LmpwZyIsImVkaXRzIjp7Im5vcm1hbGlzZSI6dHJ1ZSwicm90YXRlIjowLCJyZXNpemUiOnsid2lkdGgiOjU1NSwiaGVpZ2h0Ijo0MTYsImZpdCI6ImNvbnRhaW4iLCJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kIjp7InIiOjI1NSwiZyI6MjU1LCJiIjoyNTUsImFscGhhIjoxfX19fQ==

Comment: Parece que hay que descargarla primero

Comment: Es precisamente lo que te comenté, una url que muestra imagen, pero no es una imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, revise mejor la documentacion de la api y encontre un campo que te trae una url con imagen, esta si me la acepto la funcion de wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolvi usando el plugin visualinmueble. https://visualinmueble.com/paginas-web-para-inmobiliarias-con-wasi-simi-y-domus/